# Alphanumeric Code Generated on Button Click

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, alphanumeric

Okay.  So I'm making my first OSX app and I'm almost done.  All I'm having trouble now is making it where I click a button it edits a text field with a code in the format BBBB-BBBB-BBBB.  I've tried the code below but  I couldn't get it to do what I wanted it to do.  This is my first application and i'm having some trouble..

```
NSString *letters = @"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";

-(NSString *) randomStringWithLength: (int) len {
NSMutableString *randomString = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity: len];

for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
     [randomString appendFormat: @"%C", [letters characterAtIndex: arc4random_uniform([letters length]) % [letters length]]];
}

return randomString;
}
```

Comment: And what exactly is your question?  Where do you have your difficulty?

Comment: Please edit your question to add information, rather than trying to paste large blocks of code into a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your code like follows (use `[self randomStringWithLength:12]`):

```
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
   [randomString appendFormat:@"%C", [letters characterAtIndex:arc4random_uniform([letters length]) % [letters length]]];

    if ((i > 0) && (i + 1 < len) && (i % 4 == 3)) {
        [randomString appendString:@"-"];
    }
}
```

Comment: Now i'm getting

`No visible @interface for 'AppDelegate' declares the selector 'randomStringWithLength:'`

Comment: Then you are not implementing the method inside the correct class (`AppDelegate`)